# Adding search query back to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, web-scraping

I am trying to search news from google news. So that I can make repository of news related to few company names. I have run into two set of problems. Hoping the larger community can help me out.

Below is my code: Downloading libraries

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

pip install GoogleNews
pip install newspaper3k

from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import Config
import pandas as pd
import nltk
#config will allow us to access the specified url for which we are #not authorized. Sometimes we may get 403 client error while parsing #the link to download the article.
nltk.download('punkt')
# Mozilla/80.0
user_agent = 'Mozilla/80.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
config = Config()
```

company names:

```
cnames = ["Morgan Stanley","Evercore ISI","JP Morgan"]
```

Writing query to extract the relevant news articles based on date:

```
# def get_google_news() :
for compn in cnames :
  config = Config()
  config.request_timeout = 10
  config.browser_user_agent = user_agent
  # googlenews=GoogleNews(start='10/01/2019',end='11/01/2019')#Gives the start and end date of news
  googlenews=GoogleNews(start='10/01/2019',end='10/15/2019')
  googlenews.search(compn)

  # googlenews.get_news('Wells Fargo')
  result=googlenews.result()
  df=pd.DataFrame(result)
  print(df.head())
  for i in range(2,30):
      googlenews.getpage(i)
      result=googlenews.result()
      df=pd.DataFrame(result)
  list=[]
  for ind in df.index:
      dict={}
      article = Article(df['link'][ind],config=config)
      try :
        article.download()
        article.parse()
        article.nlp()
      except :
        pass
      dict['Date']=df['date'][ind]
      dict['Media']=df['media'][ind]
      dict['Ticker'] = df['compn'][ind]
      dict['Title']=article.title
      dict['Article']=article.text
      dict['Summary']=article.summary
      list.append(dict)
  news_df=pd.DataFrame(list)
```

1. The issue here is when I am searching the keywords example the company names:
   I am getting relevant news from those dates. But I am unable to add search key word back to
   dataframe, so that I can differentiate for which key words was I able to extract news for.

I am getting key error when I add this line:

```
dict['Ticker'] = df['compn'][ind]
```

2. As you all know googlenews only allows around 200 news articles per search query, So I need a way to somehow give the date range for every month until a year from October 1st 2019 to oct 2020.

   googlenews=GoogleNews(start='10/01/2019',end='10/15/2019')

Above code gives the date range. Is there anyway wherein I can loop over and search the keywords and get news for every month for those keywords, and join everything into a final dataframe?

Error Screenshot:USing Google colab

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'compn'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'compn'
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what error you are getting and share the full code that is causing the error? Please also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have shared the entire code. You can copy and paste the code in any environment to reproduce the error. The error screenshot also is attached for your reference.